# Is there another word for 'sentence finisher' in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

I am just interested in finding another word for *sentence finisher* in English, or basically someone who has a habit of cutting off another person's sentence and putting in their own statement.

Comment: The word for a person who is forever interrupting is *rude*.

Comment: That's true, but you can be rude for doing many different things. I am just looking for one that is for cutting people's sentences off.

Comment: You won’t find it.

Comment: Why would you want “a single word”? It’s quite clear when you use more than one word.

Comment: @tchrist - Curiosity I guess... and you always want more than one way to say something because it might be more appropriate in different settings.

Answer (score 1):

There's "buttinsky", though that's really about getting into other people's business. Maybe you could repurpose it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Merriam Webster defines ["interrupter" (or "interruptor")](http://i.word.com/idictionary/interruptor) as "one that interrupts" and, the same dictionary, defines "interrupt" (verb) as "to stop or hinder by breaking in '*interrupted the speaker with frequent questions*'", you can use "interrupter" (or "interruptor").

Incidentally, you'll find the example sentence that Merriam Webster reports fits the case in the question.

To further illustrate its usage, consider "*Interrupters* might also just be excited or eager to make their point." ([CBS NEWS](http://m.cbsnews.com/storysynopsis.rbml?&pageType=moneywatch&catid=57477278&feed_id=76&videofeed=43&nb_splitPage=1))

Comment: Is interruptor specific enough? It would apply to any action that someone was undertaking, but not specifically to speech.

Answer (score 0):

While not a single word, and without any history of use in this context, consider the term *conversational usurper*, where [usurp](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/usurper) means

> to seize, take over, or appropriate (land, a throne, etc) without authority

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean someone who appropriates your point. If you are making a point and another person breaks in to give his own interpretation of what you are trying to say, he has appropriated your point or your response. Often, the explanation used by an interrupter who takes over the sentence is not in keeping with what the speaker had in mind. That person has appropriated your argument and turned it to his own purpose. You see this in informal political debate sometimes.

Comment: Well, someone who finishes a sentence for someone else can either be saying exactly what the other person was trying to say (maybe they just want to get to the end) or something that the other person wasn't trying to say (which is what you are pointing out). It would be even better to distinguish between the two, but that would be just making things even more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single-word answer but that's because there are none, excluding "interrupter" which *kinda* gets the message across.

[to butt in](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/butt+in?s=ts)
Verb phrase: **butt in**, to meddle in the affairs or intrude in the conversation of others; interfere: It was none of his concern, so he didn't *butt in*.

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/butt-in) defines **butt in** as: *to join a conversation or activity without being asked to*

Neologic solution: a "*buttsome*" or "*buttical*" person. (a shame these adjectives do not exist)